# How to have c++ pause to wait for user input in for loop

Tags: c++

I have the following code snippet in c++

```
int main(){
  std::vector<int> numbers(10);
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
    std::cout << "Please enter number " << i << "\n";
    std::cin >> numbers[i];
  }
}
```

My hope is that for every value of i in the for loop, then code would wait for my input to enter the next number. However, instead I just get "Please enter number i" printed out 10 times, and the loop ends. I'm fairly new to c++ so I'm not too sure how to work around this, and moreover why my code is wrong.

Comment: How are you running the program?  For example: if you are redirecting input into the program then it won't wait, but if you are running the program interactively it will.

Comment: Seems to work ok to me, though if you enter non-numeric input before this you might see something like this.

Comment: Sounds a lot like you reach this code with `std::cin` in an error state. How that could have happened in this code example is beyond me. Added headers and can't reproduce at any rate. Looks good to me.

Comment: Ah I was running it without a compiler in Codecademy. I ran it via VSC through the command prompt, and everything works that way!

Comment: Side note: Do most of the development work on your PC and use the official submission tool only after you're sure there are no bugs. On your PC you'll have access to profilers, debuggers, and all sorts of other groovy tools to help you work efficiently. On the school site you're probably screwed and have to do everything the hard way..

Comment: And now that we know you were running on the school site, you might have to look around for a way to specify the input. The input could be provided via a file, and if there's nothing in the input file, `std::cin >> numbers[i];` will silently fail because of End Of File. General rule of thumb: Always check the state of the stream after every IO transaction so that you don't get any avoidable surprises. Eg: `if (std::cin >> numbers[i])) { use the number } else { handle error }`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you'll like this. contains some error checking if the expected value is a not a number or the number is to big.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <locale>  // std::stoi - string to integer ( int )
#include <stdexcept>  // exeptions

int main(){
  std::vector<int> numbers(10);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
    std::cout << "Please enter number " << i << "\n";
    std::string  temp = "";
    int temp2 = 0;
again:
    std::getline (std::cin,temp); 
    
    try{
        temp2 = std::stoi(temp);
    }
    catch (const std::invalid_argument & e) {
            std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
            std::cout << "that's no number, please, try again\n";
            goto again;
        }
    catch (const std::out_of_range & e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
        std::cout << "something bad happend, please, try again\n";
        goto again;
    }
    numbers[i] = temp2;
  }
  for(auto i : numbers)
      std::cout << i <<" ";
    std::cout<< "\n";    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It works fine, the process wait for your input every loop cycle. If you enter a non-integer number, the program will terminate earlier than it should, because the data entered is not of the appropriate type.